# How read values from MultipleSelectListPreference

Tags: java, android

I want to read my string arrays entries from `SharedPreferences` that were saved via MultipleSelectListPreferences.

`getStringSet()` seems to be the only method on SharedPreferences that fits the requirements. 
How do I extract the saved String array with this method - I don't understand how to get the array from a String set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have provided a simple example of how to read a MutipleSelectListPreference into set and then, convert it into an String array and save it into a String.

First you read your sharedPreferences into the mySet object:

```
Set<String> mySet = sharedPreferences.getStringSet('your_preference_key', new Hashset<String>());
```

Then you can define String array, iterate through the mySet and save each string into one fromSet string:

```
String fromSet;
String myArray[] = mySet.toArray(new String[mySet.size()]);
for (int index = 0; index < myArray.length; index++) {
    fromSet += myArray[index] + "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help. In your first code block, does toArray() really take those params or do they belong to getStringSet()

Comment: toArray() method belongs to Set class and it returns the String array that contains all the values contained in this set

Comment: Whar I mean is that getStringSet needs two parameter. Your statement doean't compile because you getStringSet doesn't have params specified